# Linuxのuseraddコマンドについて

Tags: linux

`useradd -u <uid> -g <group> -d <home_directory_path> <username>`

上記のようにユーザを作成した場合、<home_directory_path>が作成され、プロンプトには

`[<username>@<hostname>~]`のように表示がされます。

しかし、`<username>@<hostname>$`のように表示されるようユーザを作成にはどうすればよいでしょうか。
かつ、.bash_profileや.bashrcもちゃんと作成されるようにしたいです。

補足 : 目的としましては、新規ユーザ作成後、そのユーザでログインした際に表示を変えたいのです。

`[testuser@centos7]$`

のような感じてはなく、

`testuser@centos7$`

のように[]を表示させないようにするユーザ作成方法が知りたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[testuser@centos7]$` の部分はシェルのプロンプトと呼ばれ、`useradd` コマンドとは直接関係はありません。この部分の表示をカスタマイズしたい場合には、環境変数 `$PS1` を編集します。

`echo` コマンドで確認すると、恐らく以下のような定義になっていると思います。

```sh
$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

- `\u` ... ユーザー名
- `\h` ... ホスト名
- `\W` ... カレントディレクトリ

---

`[]` が不要な場合には、以下のように定義し直します。

```
$ export PS1="\u@\h \W\$"
```

ログインし直すと設定は元に戻ってしまうので、次回以降も永続化するには `~/.bashrc` に先程のコマンドを追記します。

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc

### ファイルの末尾に以下の行を追記
export PS1="\u@\h \W\$"
```